# Installing matplotlib on Pypy (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: matplotlib, pypy

I know there is a duplicate question but it is from 2017.

I am trying to pip install matplotlib in my conda: `pypy3 -mpip install matplotlib`

This is the error I am getting - I had to truncate the log due to SO limitations.

My understanding is matplotlib can be installed on pypy. Is this correct? If not, is there a workaround for this?

```
Collecting matplotlib
  Downloading matplotlib-3.3.0.tar.gz (38.8 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 38.8 MB 264 kB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in /opt/conda/envs/pypy3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from matplotlib) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in /opt/conda/envs/pypy3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from matplotlib) (1.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.15 in /opt/conda/envs/pypy3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from matplotlib) (1.19.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow>=6.2.0 in /opt/conda/envs/pypy3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from matplotlib) (7.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=2.0.3 in /opt/conda/envs/pypy3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from matplotlib) (2.4.7)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in /opt/conda/envs/pypy3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from matplotlib) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /opt/conda/envs/pypy3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from cycler>=0.10->matplotlib) (1.15.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: matplotlib
  Building wheel for matplotlib (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /opt/conda/envs/pypy3/bin/pypy3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-5ygoofgy/matplotlib/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-5ygoofgy/matplotlib/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-k34s3_dx
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-5ygoofgy/matplotlib/
  Complete output (873 lines):
  
  Edit setup.cfg to change the build options; suppress output with --quiet.
  
  BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
    matplotlib: yes [3.3.0]
        python: yes [3.6.9 (?, Apr 10 2020, 19:47:05) [PyPy 7.3.1 with GCC 7.3.0]]
      platform: yes [linux]
   sample_data: yes [installing]
         tests: no  [skipping due to configuration]
        macosx: no  [Mac OS-X only]
  
  
  UPDATING build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/matplotlib/_version.py
  set build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/matplotlib/_version.py to '3.3.0'
  running build_ext
  creating tmp
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for matplotlib
  Running setup.py clean for matplotlib
Failed to build matplotlib
DEPRECATION: Could not build wheels for matplotlib which do not use PEP 517. pip will fall back to legacy 'setup.py install' for these. pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality. A possible replacement is to fix the wheel build issue reported above. You can find discussion regarding this at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8368.
Installing collected packages: matplotlib
    Running setup.py install for matplotlib ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /opt/conda/envs/pypy3/bin/pypy3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-5ygoofgy/matplotlib/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-5ygoofgy/matplotlib/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-48_fnjvl/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /opt/conda/envs/pypy3/include/matplotlib
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-5ygoofgy/matplotlib/
    Complete output (610 lines):
    
    Edit setup.cfg to change the build options; suppress output with --quiet.
    
    BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
      matplotlib: yes [3.3.0]
          python: yes [3.6.9 (?, Apr 10 2020, 19:47:05) [PyPy 7.3.1 with GCC 7.3.0]]
        platform: yes [linux]
     sample_data: yes [installing]
           tests: no  [skipping due to configuration]
          macosx: no  [Mac OS-X only]
    

    set build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/matplotlib/_version.py to '3.3.0'
    running build_ext
    
    
    src/ft2font_wrapper.cpp:641:29: error: ‘PyUnicode_ReadChar’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘PyUnicode_AsWideChar’?
      641 |             codepoints[i] = PyUnicode_ReadChar(textobj, i);
          |                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
          |                             PyUnicode_AsWideChar
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /opt/conda/envs/pypy3/bin/pypy3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-5ygoofgy/matplotlib/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-5ygoofgy/matplotlib/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-48_fnjvl/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /opt/conda/envs/pypy3/include/matplotlib Check the logs for full command output.
```